# 'Navigate' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a protected route by checking if the user is signed in.  I am using React 18, Typescript, and React Router v6.
However, it keeps on complaining `'Navigate' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Navigate'?ts(2749)`

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
   children?: ReactNode;
}

const Protected = ({ children }: Props) => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
    return children;
};
export default Protected;
```

Comment: Where are you importing `Navigate` from? Needs more context.

Comment: i updated the question, it's from react-router-dom

Comment: Is this in a TSX file? What TypeScript version are you using?

Comment: yes  "typescript": "^4.4.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's some issue with your node_modules. You may want to remove the folder entirely then re-run `npm ci` or `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`. You can also remove those lock files and just do a `yarn install` or `npm install` from scratch.

Consider this barebones approach instead [with a working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-react18-2-router-6-chmgng) - flip `const isSignedIn = true;` and test the `/secret` path.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { Route, Routes as RouteSwitch } from "react-router-dom";
import Protected from "./Protected";

const PublicComponent = () => <span>hello world</span>;
const SecretComponent = () => <span>hello darkness my old friend</span>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouteSwitch>
        <Route path="/" element={<PublicComponent />} />
        <Route
          path="/secret"
          element={
            <Protected>
              <SecretComponent />
            </Protected>
          }
        />
      </RouteSwitch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Protected.tsx**

```
import { FC, ReactNode, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const isSignedIn = true;

const Protected: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSignedIn) navigate("/");
  }, [isSignedIn]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default Protected;
```